# Why is this PHP AJAX MysQl Chat Script needs page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I wrote a very simple chat script that inserts data with AJAX to avoid page refresh. The data inserts but I need to refresh the page in order to see the data that was inserted. I use jQuery to avoid page refresh. Can someone help?

**script**

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#chatForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#chatForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});

$("#chatForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#chatForm :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

**form.php**

```
    <form id="chatForm" action="chat.php" method="post">
    <input id='message' name="message" type="text" class="form form-control messageBar" placeholder="Write message here..."/>
    <input id='employee_id' name='employee_id' type="hidden" value="<?=$session_myemployeeid;?>">
    <div class='col-md-2 pull-right'>
    <button id="submit">Send Comment</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
include '../includes/config.php';

// set parameters and execute
$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

// prepare and bind
$insertchat= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO companychatroom (employee_id,message) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insertchat->bind_param("is",$employee_id,$message);
$insertchat->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 

$insertchat->close();
$db->close();
```

**display.php**

```
   <div id="displayMessage" class="displayMessage">
     <?php 
        $sqlchat="SELECT * FROM companychatroom 
        JOIN employees 
        ON companychatroom.employee_id=employees.employee_id";
        $resultchat=  mysqli_query($db,$sqlchat);
       while($chat=mysqli_fetch_array($resultchat)){ ?>
           <div class="row" style="padding:4%;">
               <p><?=$chat['first_name'];?> <?=$chat['last_name'];?></p> <div class="bubble"><?=$chat['message'];?></div>
           </div>
       <?php };?>

       </div>
```

Comment: Because there is no code in place to query the added comments in the background.

Comment: you don't echo anything from chat.php to use as ajax response

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl 's analysis. Also, I don't see any element called `#result` where the `info` is being dumped

Comment: @charlietfl: my bad I forgot to add the display.php. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Shadow: I just edited the question with the extra code I forgot.

Comment: but ajax request goes to chat.php....which doesn't appear to include display.php

Comment: @charlietfl: correct they are two separate files...

Comment: ok...so then that goes back to nothing is returned. Perhaps you need to include display.php in chat.php after the inserts are done

Comment: @charlietfl: the problem is display.php is also form.php that's the same page... Hey man feel free to share an answer if you wish to get creds im new to programming so it does not come easy for me yet... But I do understand what you're saying I'm just not sure how to make it happen lol.

Comment: @Sebastian. You need to return your marked up message from the ajax call - this will mean including the logic to query the db and mark up the result (much like what's in display.php), then echo this marked up message before exiting.  Then the AJAX success function should populate the  innerHTML  of  <div id="displayMessage"  with this string.

Comment: well it simply boils down to if you make a request and expect some html back....the place you make request to needs to be able to send it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Let's put this together into an answer:

Modify the .POST success function to move the result into the page:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#chatForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#chatForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#displayMessage").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});
```

Modify the chat.php to generate the mark up

```
<?php
include '../includes/config.php';

// set parameters and execute
$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

// prepare and bind
$insertchat= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO companychatroom (employee_id,message) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insertchat->bind_param("is",$employee_id,$message);
$insertchat->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
$insertchat->close();

$sqlchat="SELECT * FROM companychatroom 
          JOIN employees 
          ON companychatroom.employee_id=employees.employee_id";
$resultchat=  mysqli_query($db,$sqlchat);
$result = '';
while($chat=mysqli_fetch_array($resultchat)){ 
    $result .= '<div class="row" style="padding:4%;">';
    $result .= '<p>';
    $result .= $chat['first_name'].' '.$chat['last_name'];
    $result .= '</p> <div class="bubble">';
    $result .= $chat['message'];
    $result .= '</div></div>';
}
echo $result;
$db->close();
```

Change display.php to

```
<div id="displayMessage" class="displayMessage"></div>
```

DISCLAIMER - this is untested, but applying the principles demonstrated should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I just tried this and it does not insert

Comment: I do not have the time just now to debug or test. But if you understand the mechanism, you should be able to debug my code. The principle is correct - I use it all the time i.e. generate a result in the ajax call handler, echo this result back to the page, use the success function to distribute/process the result as you wish, e.g. by using it to populate a DIV if appropriate..

Comment: I have to go - can someone else see the problem in my code?

Comment: I also need to go. I will have a look tomorrow. I understand your mechanism.

Comment: A useful debugging trick is to copy the result of the ajax call to the console: so you get  function(info){ console.log(info);$("#displayMessage").html(info); 
   });

Comment: Further to my last comment, because the ajax result during debugging will often contain html, php errors, your diagnostic var_dumps etc, it's hard to read in the console. You can cut the contents of the console and paste it into a fiddle site like http://fiddlesalad.com/html/ or jsfiddle.net so you can read it. It's easiest if you clear your console before your AJAX call (Ctrl-L in Chrome).

Comment: Since form and display are on the same page, in order to echo the result should I not pass it into a SESSION variable?

Comment: Ok so for some reason it works only when I also display the while statement on the display.php same as chat.php

Comment: But then the send comment button disappears

Comment: I removed the while statement on the display.php it works for the most part... but the submit button disappears on insert. I can only insert one record at the time then I need to refresh the page to insert a new one very bizzare behavior

Comment: I just looked in the database I now understand whats going on. The messages do insert every single time. But after the first submit, the employee_id gets inserted as '0'... and since the query I wrote uses the employee_id to display the messages, the messages are not being displayed. Very strange behavior. I wonder why? Any idea?

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST) at the top of chat.php to see what's coming back from the page. It's probably a problem in your form. (I use var_dump($_REQUEST); - this includes all incoming CGI content, not just POST content, just in case.)

Comment: @Sebastian Farham - see previous comment